# How to establish communication between a webview and native design in Flutter to use an access token?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a webview to login screen. After logging in with this webview, I need to capture the access token and close the webview and continue operations from native design, how can I do this exactly in Flutter?

As I am pretty new in Flutter. I dont get idea about this handshaking.